# Given a fair dice, what is the probability that each successive number is increasing.

Tags: combinatorics

Given a fair dice with $10$ sides numbered $1$ through to $10$, I roll the dice $5$ times, what is the probability that each successive number is strictly increasing.

I really don't even know where to start. Could someone explain how this could be done.

I'm stuck on, since I can't count them, how I can split the problem up as, you can start with values of 1 to 6, then 2 to 7, but you can't have 2 if you have 6, so I dont know how to get around that

Comment: Perhaps you could explain to us how much probability you know, and where you got stuck applying your probability knowledge. If you don't know any probability whatsoever, perhaps you should start with easier questions.

Comment: When you say "increasing" do you mean *strictly* increasing or *weakly* increasing.  We should all agree that the sequence $2,3,6,8,9$ counts as increasing, but does the sequence $5,5,7,7,9$ count as increasing too?

Comment: I'm aware of probability distributions and pretty much what you'd expect from a 1st year mathematics student at uni. I'm stuck on, since I can't count them, how I can split the problem up as, you can start with values of 1 to 6, then 2 to 7, but you can't have 2 if you have 6, so I dont know how to get around that

Comment: As for counting the number of strictly increasing sequences of numbers between $1$ and $10$, consider using binomial coefficients.  As for counting the number of weakly increasing sequences, binomial coefficients will also be useful but with a twist by using instead stars-and-bars.  Once you have counted the appropriate number of sequences, then take the ratio with the number of unrestricted sequences that are possible.

Comment: How can I use binomial coefficients if order matters?

Comment: @DanD'silva because once you have picked what the five numbers are, there is one and only one way to arrange them in increasing order.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ahhh This has cleared everything up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** The set of sequences of length $5$ which are strictly increasing and whose entries are all natural numbers between $1$ and $10$ are in direct bijection with the set of size-$5$ subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$.

For example, the sequence $1,~2,~7,~8,~9$ corresponds to the subset $\{1,2,7,8,9\}$